# I am having a problem with obtaining the sum of a group of fields from MYSQL/PHP and the whole dataset of those fields without using group by

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this...

| fqid | uqid | qgrp | benlevid | planid | covrid | provid | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 812 | 143 | 24 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 1588.00 |
| 2 | 813 | 143 | 22 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 991.00 |
| 3 | 814 | 143 | 24 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 407.00 |
| 4 | 815 | 143 | 22 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 407.00 |
| 5 | 812 | 143 | 30 | 18 | 2 | 4 | 1291.00 |
| 6 | 813 | 143 | 30 | 18 | 2 | 4 | 783.00 |
| 7 | 814 | 143 | 30 | 18 | 2 | 4 | 482.00 |
| 8 | 815 | 143 | 30 | 18 | 2 | 4 | 482.00 |
| 9 | 812 | 143 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1128.00 |
| 10 | 813 | 143 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 486.00 |
| 11 | 814 | 143 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 241.00 |
| 12 | 815 | 143 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 241.00 |

I need to get a total of the rates for each qgrp and still pull all the data from the same group.

I have this mysql right now, but the group by statement is grouping the rates.

`` select *, sum(rate) `sumrate` from `ins_final_quote` where `qgrp` = 145 group by provid order by `sumrate` asc ``

I could conceivably do this with separate queries but need to build html tables with the results, so being able to do this with one query would make this task much easier. Can this be done? Or am I barking up the wrong tree? Is this even possible?

Comment: *I need to get a total of the rates for each qgrp* but you group by provid. Why?

Comment: You could do the summing in PHP. Oh, that reminds me, where's your PHP code?

Comment: Yes, I could, but if possible, I'd rather get the single array from MYSQL? No PHP code yet, trying to resolve the query results first.

Comment: @forpas This is for a quote comparison system for insurance. Each user is part of a group, a family. Each provid is a provider. I need to show bootstrap cards showing each family member's rate and a total of the rates per family. Then each card will be ordered from low to highest family rate.

Comment: "I can't show you the results." ? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kfWGDBn5zTvkifHoA8zGoz/0

Comment: @radocaw My apologies, but at the moment, I'm not near my computer, so this is the reason why I can't show the results. Once I get to my computer, I can. Though not sure when that will be today.

Comment: Well, the thing you're typing on right now will do it!!

Comment: You mean this phone? Without access to the database or GIT?

Comment: Yep. That one will do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understood the query, but the answer is to use [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) like this:

```
mysql> select *, sum(rate) over(partition by qgrp) `sumrate` 
       from `ins_final_quote` order by qgrp;
+----+------+------+----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| id | uqid | qgrp | benlevid | panid | covrid | provid | rate    | sumrate |
+----+------+------+----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
|  9 |  815 |  141 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  482.00 |  982.00 |
| 12 |  815 |  141 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  500.00 |  982.00 |
| 11 |  815 |  142 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  482.00 |  482.00 |
|  1 |  812 |  143 |       24 |     7 |      2 |      1 | 1588.00 | 6913.00 |
|  2 |  813 |  143 |       22 |     6 |      2 |      1 |  991.00 | 6913.00 |
|  3 |  814 |  143 |       24 |     7 |      2 |      1 |  407.00 | 6913.00 |
|  4 |  815 |  143 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  407.00 | 6913.00 |
|  5 |  812 |  143 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 | 1291.00 | 6913.00 |
|  6 |  813 |  143 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  783.00 | 6913.00 |
|  7 |  814 |  143 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  482.00 | 6913.00 |
|  8 |  815 |  143 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  482.00 | 6913.00 |
| 10 |  815 |  143 |       30 |    18 |      2 |      4 |  482.00 | 6913.00 |
+----+------+------+----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: This is quite nice, it's like a sub-query in disguise. It could be as efficient as doing the same thing in PHP, but only real-case testing can tell you that.

Comment: This would be perfect if the math was correct. The object is to get the total of the rate fields according to provid. So for example, for provid 1, the sumrate field would have the total of id 1, 2, 3. In your example, the rest of sumrate would have the total of all the others.

Comment: @hasherfer I cannot test it, but would `sum(rate) over(partition by provid) \`sumrate\`` work?

Comment: No, the math is still all wrong.  I can't show you the results. Can't post an image nor make a table. Or don't know how.

Comment: @hasherfer: the math might be wrong because the number I added are not the same as yours of course, but you get the idea on how to group. Your question was about `qgrp` but you can change that of course.

Comment: @hasherfer No sir, I understood that. They are wrong on my data.